# How to supply a ball in a circle always bounces to direction of surface normal vectors in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, 2d

[image]

or

[Alternative link for the picture](https://pasteboard.co/ICgchoh.png)

This is my problem, I have a  ball inside a circle, they are all in 2d World, and I want my ball to bounce evey time according to surface normal. How can I do that?

I designed it like that I have 2 scripts for one of the is attached to red ball and its name BallScript and another is for bounce button called Bounce script.

BallScript.cs is like these as the answer below;

```
private ContactPoint contact;
public static Vector3 temp;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
  temp = Vector3.Reflect(circle.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity, contact.normal);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision)
{
    contact = collision.contacts[0];
}
```

and Bounce.cs for the bounce button is like this;

```
ball.velocity = new Vector3(0, 5.5f, 0) + BallScript.temp;
```

With these update as the answers below, I got close but sometimes circle bounce to the right normal vector position (for example if you are in the bottom right are of the big circle, ball must bounce to the left, if the ball is inside the bottom left side of the circle it must bounce to the right) but sometimes it is bouncing in wrong direction. Think that it is bouncing right sometimes and sometimes bouncing in the mirror view.

until now I tried lots of things but until I want a way to my desire, I simulated the action as below with the bounce script;

```
        if (circle.transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            ball.velocity = new Vector3(3f, 5f, 0);
        }
        if (circle.transform.position.x > 0)
        {
            ball.velocity = new Vector3(-3f, 5f, 0);
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.vector?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks @JohnPete22 I wanted to mean that in Unity.

Comment: Okay.  Please update your question with the solution(s) you have tried and the error message(s) you received, and we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Thank. I updated problem but I got a little bit more close to the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Rigidbody2D rb;<br>
private void Start(){
   this.rb = circle.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
//Don't do it here.......
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision)
{
   Vector3 directionToGo = Vector3.Reflect(this.rb.velocity, collision.contacts[0].normal);
}
```

ball.rigidbody.velocity=> The velocity of the ball which is inside the circle.
collision.contacts[0].normal=> The object's collider that gets returned on collision to the ball.

It will return the reflection vector after collision.

Comment: I updated script and edited my question. Could you please look at it again?

Comment: Thanks I tried this also but did not work as I want. Normal vector's x and y is changing in very different ways and when I applied a foce to circle, it bounces sometimes fast and sometimes wierd. So, until I find a solution, I simulated the action as the code below to the bounce script.

            if (circle.transform.position.x < 0)
            {
                ball.velocity = new Vector3(3f, 5f, 0);
            }
            if (circle.transform.position.x > 0)
            {
                ball.velocity = new Vector3(-3f, 5f, 0);
            }
I added the code to my question